# What is a substitution pattern?

Tags: microeconomics

I know what substitution effect is but I am not sure what substitution patterns are. To give some context the author says the following:

"I analyze the substitution patterns between exchange transplants and other transplant outcomes"

What does this mean in layman terms?

Comment: It would help if you can provide a more specific context to that quote. Who said it, where, and in what context?

Comment: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/88aa/5bd94afd4893a8a809029199de6a4f762f0c.pdf

Comment: The quoted text is not in this pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that phrase in the linked PDF, but I don't think these terms are being used in a manner particularly special to economics, and this would probably be better suited to English Language SE. "substitution" means having one thing instead of another, and "pattern" means "repeated form". "substitution patterns between exchange transplants and other transplant outcomes" would, I think, be better phrased as "patterns of substitution of exchange for other transplant outcomes". "substitution of exchange for other transplant outcomes" refers to when an exchange happens, instead of something else, and "patterns of substitution of exchange for other transplant outcomes" means "attributes that are common to substitution of exchange for other transplant outcomes". That is, the whole phrase refers to what we can expect when an exchange happens, rather than something else.